# load multiple images to imageslideshow in swift5

Tags: ios, swift, image, alamofire, slideshow

I am fetching data using alamofire to my app then to tableview then to details view, I have two columns of images in my database one named "document" and the second named "document2" some rows has images in document and others on document2, so when I load the images using my code below it loads only one image

```js
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import SDWebImage
import SwifterSwift
import Kingfisher
import ImageSlideshow




class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {


var data: JSON?


@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView2: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var AdTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var AdDetails: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var ContactBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var ShareBtn: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var DateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var CityLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imagesSlideshowView: ImageSlideshow!






override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    if let id = Helper.getUserId() {
        ContactBtn.isHidden = false
    } else {
        ContactBtn.isHidden = true
    }
    
    AdDetails.textContainer.heightTracksTextView = true
    AdDetails.isScrollEnabled = false
    //self.navigationController?.navigationBar.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    let PostTitle = data!["title"].string
    self.title = PostTitle!
                
     


    
    let imageUrl = data!["document"].string
    let url = NSURL(string:("https://site/uploads/" + imageUrl!))

    let imageUrl2 = data!["document2"].string
    let Image2url = NSURL(string:("https://site/uploads/" + imageUrl2!))
    imageView.sd_setImage(with: url as URL?, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
    
        
    
    CityLabel.text = data!["city"].string
    AdTitle.text = data!["title"].string
    AdDetails.text = data!["message"].string
    
    let PostTime = data!["time"].string!
    
    let startDate = PostTime
    
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: startDate)
    
    let converted = date?.timeAgoDisplay()
    DateLabel.text = date?.timeAgoDisplay()
    
    let uploadsBaseUrl = "https://site/uploads/"
    var imagesSlideshowView = ImageSlideshow()
    if let image1urlString = data?["document"].string,
       let image1url = URL(string: uploadsBaseUrl + image1urlString),
       let image2urlString = data?["document2"].string,
       let image2url = URL(string: uploadsBaseUrl + image2urlString) {

        var imagesSources: [KingfisherSource] = []
        imagesSources.append(KingfisherSource(url: image1url))
        imagesSources.append(KingfisherSource(url: image2url))

        imagesSlideshowView.setImageInputs(imagesSources)
        let pageIndicator = UIPageControl()
        pageIndicator.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        pageIndicator.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
        imagesSlideshowView.pageIndicator = pageIndicator
        
    }
```

now I added a view and installed the required libs,

ImageSlideshow
Kingfisher
ImageSlideshow/Kingfisher
ImageSlideshow/Alamofire
ImageSlideshow/SDWebImage
still images are not passed to the view ?!

Updated the code to make it as slideshow as suggested by @denis-kozhukhov

Comment: As I see you take only one image here (let image = Image2url). Why you ever need webkit for this?

Comment: @DenisKozhukhov yeah, let image = Image2url but how can I combined the two columns to show all images in document and document2, and I want to view the photos in the webkit with the rest of the data,

Comment: I don't understand the problem - you have two images but to webkit you pass only one - why you not pass first one? Why you use webkit for presentation, why not standard ios iu elements? what benefits of webkit you use? Please, provide more info - images you have, desired effects you want to achive.

Comment: @DenisKozhukhov what if i will pass the images to a collection view will it work perfect? I   am new to swift and xcode that's why

Comment: If you want to display two images - you have to use (or pass) two image in any way. and you don't need to force unwrap data in such if let unwrapping (avoid force anwrap as much as possible).

Answer (score 0):

I don't clear understand what do you want to achieve, but will try to make something with your code, maybe you need something like this:

```swift
import UIKit
import ImageSlideshow
import ImageSlideshowKingfisher

class SomeController: UIViewController {

    let uploadsBaseUrl = "https://mysite.co/uploads/"
    var imagesSlideshowView: ImageSlideshow!

    func viewCreateFunc() {
        imagesSlideshowView = ImageSlideshow(frame: someFrame)
        self.addSubview(imagesSlideshowView)
    }

    func imagesUpdateFunc() {
        if let image1urlString = data?["document"]?.string,
           let image1url = URL(string: uploadsBaseUrl + image1urlString),
           let image2urlString = data?["document2"]?.string,
           let image2url = URL(string: uploadsBaseUrl + image2urlString) {

            var imagesSources: [KingfisherSource] = []
            imagesSources.append(KingfisherSource(url: image1url))
            imagesSources.append(KingfisherSource(url: image2url))

            imagesSlideshowView.setImageInputs(imagesSources)
            // removed html prepare code
        }
    }
}
```

I update your code to it be more safe and clear, change naming.

Also I added to code the usage of ImageSlideshow with Kingfisher (I see you use SDWebImage, but I now don't use it and don't have option to make code for it, but is mostly similar).

Comment: thanks Denis actually what I want to do is to load the other images in column document2 in in another imageview and loop the images to show them all, is that possible?

Comment: you want two show two images at once on one screen or show one image and have slide/swipe action to change it to another (some type of image carousel). On your words I now see - you want to have second one. So you need to use some type of scrolling view or maybe third-party lib for images carousel - for example ImageSlideshow (search for it on github). I update my answer, added some code how to use ImageSlideshow here.

Comment: Thanks @denis-kozhukhov I will not use webkit and I will try it and see

Comment: I installed all the required libs but it says Cannot find type 'KingfisherSource' in scope ?

Comment: You need also the Kingfisher lib itself, look at github for it too

Comment: I updated the code in the main thread, but still images are not passed to the view!

Comment: It's not possible to understand the problem without full code there you create the view, it's subviews, code from where you pass the data. imagesSlideshowView it's view and it must be added as subview for example, I don't see it in your code. Mine code is just example of code, not the full project you already can use - I can't make it because don't know all your code and how you work work it, how you work with ui. Previously you had some imageView - it was declared somehow and somehow added to controller - imagesSlideshowView is the similar view and must be used in similar way.

Comment: sorry I thought I added my full code, full code added now for the viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Simply do it

```
pod "ImageSlideshow/SDWebImage"
```

Run pod install

**make data source like this**

```
import SDWebImage



func displayImages(){
        var imageSDWebImageSrc = [SDWebImageSource]()
        for (_,i) in (newsModel?.banners ?? [Banner]()).enumerated() {
            let image = SDWebImageSource(urlString: i.image ?? "")
            if let sdURL = image{
                imageSDWebImageSrc.append(sdURL)
            }
        }
        imageSlider.reloadInputViews()
    }
```